# Cordova app back button not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have the following code which is supposed to prevent the back button from exiting the app and just show an alert. The alert comes up but after i hit "ok", it still exits the app. I have no idea why the preventDefault isn't working.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('Back Button is Pressed!');
}
```

Comment: i just did..that still did not work

Comment: then try if(!$rootScope.$viewHistory.backView){
  $scope.backButton = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction( function () {
   $ionicViewService.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true });
   $state.go('home');
  }, 105 );
  $scope.$on('$destroy', $scope.backButton);
 }
})

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900211/ionic-prevent-exit-app-on-hardware-back-button

Comment: This code must be inside of "deviceready" event listener.